# How to compare a container image build via docker and pushed via buildah

Tags: docker-build, buildah

The images are getting build using docker and gets pushed to ecr.

There is a situation where at partner site, image are pulled using buildah from our ecr (source) and then pushed to their own ECR (destination).

Both pull and push works fine using buildah at partner site

however sha of the image at source (our ecr) and parter's ecr (destination) is different

However if images are pulled locally from sources and destination, and if we check digest using below command, they does matches

```
buildah images --digests

xxxxDestinationxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx   latest   sha256:da29964cc1dee532c58d11756f8776a1d1c7695a31b8523fc2289c1971a55f62   8b0b6f04a580   56 minutes ago      9.56 GB
xxxxsourcexxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx   latest   sha256:da29964cc1dee532c58d11756f8776a1d1c7695a31b8523fc2289c1971a55f62   8b0b6f04a580   56 minutes ago      9.56 GB
```

however it does not matches in their respective ECR repository.

is there any way these sha can match in ECR repo as well in source and destination. without changing building of images at source using buildah